# Android DropBox API - stop url redirect

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I have an app which will send a file in the background to my app folder in DropBox.

I have been testing my android app when there is no connection and I have found that if a session cannot be established, the web broswer is launched and the user is redirected to the drop box app folder.

How can I stop the web browser redirect? I dont want the user to know we are using drop box for file backups. If there is an error with the connection then i do not want the web browser to launch.

I am using the UploadPicture.java example from the [DropBox API developers site](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/files#android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a internet connection is available, and if yes you can start the upload task, else do nothing.

An example on how to check internet connectivity can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)